# Как вывести заказы в личном кабинете Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В личном кабинете в разделе "заказы" они выводятся, но я хочу что бы они выводились сразу же при входе в ЛК. Я добавил экшн который подключает orders.php в my-account.php. Но тогда вукоммерс просит переменные которые содержатся в orders.php. Я попробовал задать парочку из них вручную (совсем не уверен что стоило это делать):

```
    $has_orders = true;

    $customer_orders_arr = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),  'post_status' 
        => array( 'wc-processing'),
        ) );

        $customer_orders = (object)$customer_orders_arr;
```

и вот что получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь день пытаюсь решить эту проблему, все идеи уже закончились. Буду рад новым!

Answer (score 0):

в dashboard.php вывести можно заказы

````
    $query = new WC_Order_Query(
        array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC', 
            'date_created' => '<' . ( time() - HOUR_IN_SECONDS ),// заказы до даты
            'return' => 'ids', // получаем id заказов, получить объекты 'objects'
            'status' => 'completed',// статус
            'currency' => 'USD',//валюта 
        )
    );
    print_r($query);
```
````

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я так и сделал